# Setting up QGIS Server/Lizmap with PostGIS database

Tags: qgis, postgis, lizmap

I've installed Lizmap and set up a local PostgreSQL database for Lizmap configurations. Now I'm trying to run a new QGIS Project with the layers saved in a PostGIS/PostgreSQL database (also local) but Lizmap keeps loading the Map and there is an error message: "service non disponible!"

[image: Error Message: "Service non disponible"]

Do I need to configure the PostGIS database (user, pw,..) anywhere else besides the QGIS Project itself in the Lizmap respository? (as I did with the Lizmap Admin PostgreSQL db). How can I find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Can you check in your Lizmap configuration that the QGIS Server URL is correct?

Comment: Can you check that your QGIS Server is working correctly? (IP, port, GetCapabilities)

Comment: @etrimaille QGIS Server is working correctly. Demo Projects/own projects with Shapefiles/SQLite File can be displayed. My WMS-Server URL is set to 'http://localhost/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe'. The problems are only related to connected PostGIS Layers.

Comment: Ok, just debugging step by step. Can you have the GetCapabilities of the project asking QGIS Server without using Lizmap? How did you store in user/password? Using plain text in the QGS file? Can you check QGIS logs after your have hit your Lizmap webpage?

Comment: Yes, GetCapabilites does work on the QGIS Server. I tried to store the user/password in the authentication configuration as well as in the basic tab (plain-text) for the project. The logs indicate that there is no password supplied: "WARNING PostGIS[10332]: Connection to database failed
fe_sendauth: no password supplied"

Comment: Yes, if you use the authentification system, you need to provide the password in the QGIS server config. This is specific to QGIS Server, not lizmap. Better check first if using plain password in QGS file is working first.

Comment: Do I need to provide the password in the "httpd_qgis(-ltr).conf" file in OSGeo directory? How exactly do I provide the password? (variable?)

Comment: You should have a look to the QGIS Server documentation about this ; https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/auth_system/auth_workflows.html#qgis-server-support You need to provide both the master password and the authentification database if you really want to use authentification system on the server side.

Comment: Ok, I made a completely new project with the password saved as plain text and it's now working. But for best practice I'll try to integrate the approach with the master password and authentification database. Thanks @etrimaille!

Comment: Ok, the first step is working. (a project with plain password). Now, for the next step, you need to configure QGIS Server with the master password and the password file according to the documentation. I'm going to write my answer, please vote for it. Thanks for using Lizmap!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the discussion in comments, it seems you are using a Postgresql connexion with the Authentification system (no password in the QGS file).

Try first a QGS project with normal credentials in it, it should work. This would allow us to confirm that your QGIS Server and Lizmap install are working fine.

Then, if you still want to use the Authentification system, you need to setup QGIS Server following the documentation https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/auth_system/auth_workflows.html#qgis-server-support

You can also read the QGIS Server logs, it would tell you that it can't access your layers due to the password.